# Generate specific data from database?

Tags: php, database, forms

I have been working a some code that contains a form which asks you to enter the ID of a customer and once the form is submitted the PHP behind the form will access the database and display a table of information on the ID that was entered.

However my PHP doesn't seem to be working, when i enter an ID and hit submit i get this error message "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '= '987451'' at line 1"

Here is my HTML :

```
<body>

<h1>Task 8</h1>

<form id="customerform" action="task8.php" method="get">

<p>please fill in the following form</p>
<p>Customer ID:  <input type="text" name="custID" /><br/>
<p><input type="submit"  value="Submit">
<input type="reset" value="Reset"></p>
</form>

</body>
```

Here is my PHP :

```
<body>

<?php
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "twa312", "dam6av9a");
mysql_select_db("warehouse312", $conn)
or die ('Database not found ' . mysql_error() );

$cust = $_GET["custID"];
$sql = "select * from orders";
$sql = $sql . "where customerID = '$cust'";
$rs = mysql_query($sql, $conn)
or die ('Problem with query' . mysql_error());
?>

<p>information for customer ID <?php echo $cust ?> :</p>

<?php if (mysql_num_rows($rs)>0){ ?>

<table width="700" border="1" cellpadding="10" summary="Customer Details">

<tr>
<th>Order Number</th>
<th>Order Date</th>
<th>Shipping Date</th>
</tr>

<?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) { ?>

<tr>
<td><?php echo $row["orderNumber"]?></td>
<td><?php echo $row["orderDate"]?></td>
<td><?php echo $row["shippingDate"]?></td>
</tr>

<?php } mysql_close($conn); ?>

</table>

<?php } 
else {?> <p>No customer with ID <?php echo $cust ?> in the database</p>
<?php } ?>

</body>
```

If you need any more information just ask and any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: Please stop using `mysql_` functions, they're deprecated. Use `mysqli_` or PDO instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing a space between your tablename name and `WHERE`:

```
$sql = "select * from orders";
$sql = $sql . "where customerID = '$cust'";
```

should be

```
$sql = "select * from orders";
$sql = $sql . " where customerID = '$cust'";
```

or just

```
$sql = "select * from orders where customerID = '$cust'";
```

[Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [red box](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Also, you're wide open to [SQL injections](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174)

Comment: The new PDO interface is quite object-oriented, and being a .NET programmer for more than a decade fits fine with me, but is there a more **script like way** to send prepared and parameterized queries?

Comment: What is "script like way"?

Comment: I had a feeling it would be something annoying like a missing space, thanks a lot!